# What effect does setting android:menuCategory attribute have?

Tags: android, xml, menu

In Android menu resource, What's the difference whether android:menuCategory attribute exists or not?

I read document and created small test code but I can't make head or tail of meaning of this attribute and constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using android:menuCategory tags you specify the category of the group of the menu items and define the item's priority.

Comment: Can you please show an example of what it does in certain cases ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exactly use cases of `menuCategory` but i used it in project where I had a HomeFragment and i could go from that to LoginFragment. In LoginFragment i had a menu(on top right) for going to SettingsFragment.

When i go to settings and come back, it comes back to Home page not Login page.But i want it to come back where it was before(to login page). Therefore i used menuCategory, and it worked

```
<item
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
    android:title="Settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```